# How to call a procedure depending on a cell value in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have written different procedures on different worksheet in a Workbook. I want to call a particular procedure depending on the specific cell value in a worksheet.

I tried with defining a variable

**Example:**

Suppose, Worksheet.Range("C6")=RC

So i defined a variable ' i '

```
i= thisworkbook.sheets("Sheet1").range("C6").value

Call i
```

but I'm getting errors in this.

value Range C6 is changing as per contents it has array of total 32 contents, so I have written 32 procedures different. i just need to call each procedure depending on the value of 'C6'.

Its total 32 Procedures, i can write with the IF condition but it will be too bulky so i'm trying for some easy method.

Comment: *Welcome to [so]!* - Can you please [edit] your question to include the section of code that's giving you the error.  Also see how to create a **[mcve]** an also "[ask]".

Comment: If you're getting errors, you should include those (text, not screenshots). That might help solving what goes wrong. At the moment it's quite difficult to understand what your actual problem is.

Comment: Thank you for your response, its showing error on  '  Call i  '

Error : Compile error:
           Expected Sub,Function,or Property

Answer (score 2):

Use `Application.Run` rather than `Call`:

Say we put the name of a macro in **A1**, then:

```
Sub MAIN()
    Dim WhichMac As String
    WhichMac = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
    Application.Run WhichMac
End Sub

Sub MyMac()
    MsgBox "Hello World"
End Sub
```

[image]

`MAIN()` will call the macro whose name you have placed in **A1**.

Comment: Thank you @Gary's Student, i tried it just now,is it necessary that macro which we want to call should be in the same module..??

Comment: Thank you so much @Gary's Student i tried it properly & its working too fine... :)

Comment: @AkshayJadhav  It can be in a different module in the **same workbook**.